# WPF Image inside Grid won't align

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, grid, itemtemplate

I have a Listbox with this format

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbAlbumSelect"
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                       <Button Click="lbAlbumSelect_OnSelectionChanged">
                                   <Button.Content>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"  />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                             <Image Grid.Column="0" 
                                                               Source="{Binding album_img_src}"
                                                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                                                                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                                                   TextAlignment="Right"
                                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                                                   Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                                                   Text="{Binding album_name}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                   </Button.Content>
                     </Button>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

And It shows data like this

[image: Uncorrect display]

But I want to show data like this

[image: Correct display]

Without `HorizontalContentAlignment` set to `Stretch`, the `ListBoxItem`s wouldn't occupy all the Width of the Parent Control, so I can't remove it. But why `Horizontal Alignment=Left` in `Image` doesn't work? Is it overridden or something?

Comment: Try setting the horizontal content alignment on the button to left.

Comment: Just a note. It doesn't make sense to have a Button in the ItemTemplate of a ListBox that triggers a SelectedChanged handler. Attach a handler for the ListBox's SelectedChanged event instead. Then drop the Button and use the Grid as top-level element of the DataTemplate.

Comment: @Kavish solution worked, thanks a lot. Clemens will try that ASAP, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a Button in the ItemTemplate to trigger a SelectionChanged event. Attach a handler for the ListBox's [`SelectedChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx) event instead:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         SelectionChanged="lbAlbumSelect_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding album_img_src}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Center"
                           Text="{Binding album_name}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The event handler method gets a `SelectionChangedEventArgs` parameter, which can be used to determine in which way the selection has changed:

```
private void lbAlbumSelect_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

---

Please note also that there are widely accepted naming convention in the .NET world, where you would use CamelCase for property names. So your view model properties should be `AlbumName` and `AlbumImgSrc` (or better `AlbumImageSource`).

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the code by adding a SelectionChanged handler and removing the Button (no more alignment troubles!). Also, thanks for the CamelCase advices

Answer (score 0):

That's right. Inside DataTemplate never set event handler as it may not work properly. I've reviewed your code, if you want to achieve that desired result you need specify width and height of image.
Try this, I refactored your code

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbAlbumSelect"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Margin="2">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image  Source="{Binding album_img_src}"
                                Margin="4"
                               Height="75"
                               Width="75"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                               TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                               Margin="4"
                               Text="{Binding album_name}" 
                                   TextAlignment="Justify"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Let me know if I correctly answered your question.